# npm install throwing error in node-sass

Tags: node.js, npm, node-sass

```
node-sass@2.1.1 install /home/user/Documents/project/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

WARN invalid config loglevel="notice"
Can not download file from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sass/node-sass-binaries/v2.1.1/linux-x64-node-8.2/binding.node

> node-sass@2.1.1 postinstall /home/user/Documents/project/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

module.js:487
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/user/Documents/project/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/pangyp/bin/node-gyp'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:575:3
Build failed
added 2186 packages in 42.166s
```

I tried so far:

npm rebuild

npm rebuild node-sass

npm uninstall -g node-sass

rm -rf node_module

Comment: It seems you need to have `node-gyp` installed. `npm install -g node-gyp`

Comment: `node-sass@2.1.1` is severely outdated (I tried installing it and was able to reproduce the error); you can try editing `package.json` to use the most recent version instead. (remove `@2.1.1)`

Comment: TLDR: replace node-sass with sass. Also not to be "that guy" but there are a lot of wildly incorrect or just strange answers here. Don't bother with python or ruby or node-gyp, just replace it with the pure JS sass - it's identical but takes about 1% of the time to install and won't cause headaches in different envs.

Answer (score 26):

1. Remove '**node-sass**' dependency from your **package.json**
2. run **npm install**
3. run **npm i sass**
4. run **npm start**

You're ready to go! :)

Comment: Thanks alot. Saved me days of headaches

Comment: I LOVE YOU!!!!

Thank you! Moving from node-sass to sass did it for me! After half a day of trying the deprecate-Node-version route and upgrade-node-sass-version route... Thank you so much!

Comment: Wonderful! I'm old-school and didn't know there was a pure JS implementation of sass.

Comment: Edited your answer Usama, hope that's okay.

Answer (score 12):

You need to do next steps and it should work:

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json 
npm install --saveDev node-sass@4.5.3 
npm install
```

Voila :)

Comment: what is the significance of specific version 4.5.3? How to determine this version for my environment? My package.json is tryign to install ^4.11.0 node-sass

Answer (score 4):

by using yarn run:

```
yarn add node-sass
```

Answer (score 4):

node-sass has minimum dependency according to the version of node installed in your system. You can find out the minimum version required [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass)

Answer (score 4):

Removed `package-lock.json`, installed `Python 2.7`, added an `env variable` for python path.
Ran `npm install`.
Voila !

Answer (score 3):

Use

- Node : v14.16.0
- node-sass: ^4.14.1

it works for me

Answer (score 3):

This question is old, but if you arrive here in 2022 or later, then this info may be useful:

`node-sass` is deprecated. Now you should use `sass`.

That's why the answer given by Usama Muhammad works. Hope this helps.

Sources:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/dart-sass

Answer (score 2):

1. Delete package-lock.json
2. Remove 'node-sass' dependency from your package.json
3. run npm install
4. run npm gulp-sass --save-dev
5. run npm i -d sass
6. run npm start

Answer (score 1):

The minimum version with Node 8 support is `4.5.3`. Offhand, I don't think 2.x will support anything above Node 0.12, which is EOL.

Answer (score 0):

I have found I get node-sass errors when trying to install over a corporate proxy. The first solution is to ensure your .npmrc file has proxy allowance.

### .npmrc

```
# Try removing reference to registry, as sometimes your local corporate registry of node_modules may not include node-sass
# // registry=https://....

# note if using special characters in pass, encode them: eg: h@ppy = h%40ppy
strict-ssl=false
proxy=http://<username>:<pass>@proxyhost:<port>
https-proxy=http://<uname>:<pass>@proxyhost:<port>
```

## NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0

Then in command line before running any install

```
set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0
```

### Zip node-binding files from node-sass github site in order to download them over corporate network.

Example:
https://github.com/inspiraller/node-sass-bindings

Answer (score 0):

Add manually in package.json :  "node-sass": "4.13.0"

and update package.json in terminal `npm install`