# Why NPM install installing older version of node-sass

Tags: node-modules, npm-install, node-sass

I understand `npm install` will install the node module versions which are defined in package.json. I am not understanding why it is attempting to install an older version 4.9.1 instead of installing 4.11.0 or higher version. Because of this, I am getting below error. Could someone help me how to fix this?

> Cannot download
>   "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.9.1/win3
>   2-ia32-67_binding.node":
>
> HTTP error 404 Not Found

**Environement:**
Node version: v11.0.0 (32bit)
Visual Studio 2017

**package.json**

```
{
"name": "mydotnetcoreapp",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "",
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:watch": "ng build --watch --output-path=dist-dev",
    "build:dev": "ng build --output-path=dist-dev",
    "build:prod": "ng build --prod --output-path=dist-prod --output-hashing=none",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
},
"author": "xxxx",
"license": "",
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.5",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.5",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.5",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.2",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "highcharts": "^6.0.2",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.4",
    "ng2-scroll-to-el": "^1.0.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^2.2.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.5.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.5",
    "@types/highcharts": "^5.0.12",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/lodash-es": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.90",
    "chrome": "^0.1.0",
    "codelyzer": "^3.2.2",
    "del": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-cssmin": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-marbles": "^0.3.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "launcher": "0.0.1",
    "merge-stream": "^1.0.1",
    "natives": "^1.1.6",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.8.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
}
```

}

Comment: As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52499617/what-is-the-difference-between-npm-install-and-npm-ci), it is now recommended to use `npm ci` instead of `npm install` to install the node packages. Besides, node-sass is known to raise issues for installing, but there is a workaround in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45589179/npm-install-throwing-error-in-node-sass).

Answer (score 1):

npm install --save-dev node-sass@4.5.3