# Can't install my project. I download primevue repository from github. When i install dependencies, an error is displayed

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, npm-install, node-sass

I download primevue repository by ZIP from github. When i install dependencies,  an error is displayed. When I open the project and type "npm i", I get an error node-sass and and nothing is installed. My node version is v16.13.0.

PACKAGE.JSON

```
{
    "name": "sakai-vue",
    "version": "3.2.0",
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/primefaces/sakai-vue.git"
    },
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build",
        "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
        "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "eslint": "^6.7.2",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.2"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "0.19.0",
        "chart.js": "3.3.2",
        "core-js": "3.6.5",
        "primeflex": "3.0.0",
        "primeicons": "5.0.0",
        "primevue": "3.9.1",
        "prismjs": "1.9.0",
        "vue": "3.2.9",
        "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0"
    }
}
```

CONSOLE ERROR

```
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated eslint-loader@2.2.1: This loader has been deprecated. Please use eslint-webpack-plugin
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated html-webpack-plugin@3.2.0: 3.x is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
npm WARN deprecated axios@0.19.0: Critical security vulnerability fixed in v0.21.1. For more information, see https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3410
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\project\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\project\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\project\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\project\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\project\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\project\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\project\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\project\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\project\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\project\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\project\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\project\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\project\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\project\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\project\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\project\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\project\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\project\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\project\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\project\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\project\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\project\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\project\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\project\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\project\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\project\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\project\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
npm ERR! gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\project\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\project\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at callback (C:\project\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:299:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\project\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\project\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-19T05_37_01_986Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60394291/error-node-modules-node-sass-command-failed)?

Comment: I tried to install last version of node-sass 6+ but not installed

Comment: The issue is definitely with the versions of node and other dependencies.

Comment: The error says it can't find python. Have you installed python?

Comment: "I download primevue repository by ZIP from github." - this is not primevue but admin theme project. See https://github.com/sass/node-sass#node-version-support-policy . "node-sass": "^4.12.0" won't work with Node 16.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69504798/forked-vuejs-app-gives-error-on-npm-install