# Why am I getting this error when running: npm run build?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

```
$ npm install

npm ERR! code 1 npm ERR! path
/Users/adservice.io/Documents/GitHub/kasteel-dehaar/js/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /usr/local/bin/node
/Users/adservice.io/Documents/GitHub/kasteel-dehaar/js/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js
rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags=
--libsass_library= npm ERR!   c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-
-I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/include/node -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/src -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/constants.o.d.raw
-c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/constants.o ../src/libsass/src/constants.cpp npm ERR!   c++
'-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1'
'-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1'
'-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS'
'-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1'
'-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64'
'-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS'
'-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"'
-I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/include/node -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/src -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/context.o.d.raw
-c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/context.o ../src/libsass/src/context.cpp npm ERR!   c++
'-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1'
'-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1'
'-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS'
'-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1'
'-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64'
'-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS'
'-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"'
-I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/include/node -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/src -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/cssize.o.d.raw
-c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/cssize.o ../src/libsass/src/cssize.cpp npm ERR!   c++
'-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1'
'-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1'
'-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS'
'-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1'
'-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64'
'-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS'
'-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"'
-I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/include/node -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/src -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/emitter.o.d.raw
-c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/emitter.o ../src/libsass/src/emitter.cpp npm ERR!   c++
'-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1'
'-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1'
'-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS'
'-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1'
'-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64'
'-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS'
'-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"'
-I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/include/node -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/src -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/environment.o.d.raw
-c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/environment.o ../src/libsass/src/environment.cpp npm ERR!   c++
'-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1'
'-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1'
'-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS'
'-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1'
'-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64'
'-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS'
'-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"'

'-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1'
'-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1'
'-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS'
'-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1'
'-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64'
'-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS'
'-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"'
-I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/include/node -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/src -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/values.o.d.raw
-c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/values.o ../src/libsass/src/values.cpp npm ERR!   rm -f Release/sass.a &&
./gyp-mac-tool filter-libtool libtool  -static -o Release/sass.a
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast_fwd_decl.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/backtrace.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/base64vlq.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/bind.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/cencode.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/check_nesting.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/color_maps.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/constants.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/context.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/cssize.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/emitter.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/environment.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/error_handling.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/eval.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/expand.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/extend.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/file.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/functions.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/inspect.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/json.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/lexer.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/listize.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/memory/SharedPtr.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/node.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/operators.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/output.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/parser.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/plugins.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/position.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/prelexer.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/remove_placeholders.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/sass.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/sass2scss.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/sass_context.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/sass_functions.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/sass_util.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/sass_values.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/source_map.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/subset_map.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/to_c.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/to_value.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/units.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/utf8_string.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/util.o
Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/values.o npm ERR!   c++
'-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=binding' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1'
'-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1'
'-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS'
'-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1'
'-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64'
'-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS'
'-DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION'
-I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/include/node -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/src -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/deps/v8/include -I../../nan -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o.d.raw   -c -o
Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o ../src/binding.cpp npm ERR!
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok npm ERR! gyp verb cli [ npm ERR!
gyp verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/node', npm ERR! gyp verb cli  
'/Users/adservice.io/Documents/GitHub/kasteel-dehaar/js/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild', npm ERR! gyp verb cli  
'--verbose', npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=', npm ERR! gyp
verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=', npm ERR! gyp verb cli  
'--libsass_ldflags=', npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' npm
ERR! gyp verb cli ] npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0 npm ERR!
gyp info using node@16.14.0 | darwin | x64 npm ERR! gyp verb command
rebuild [] npm ERR! gyp verb command clean [] npm ERR! gyp verb clean
removing "build" directory npm ERR! gyp verb command configure [] npm
ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in
the PATH npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python2
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2 npm ERR!
gyp verb check python version
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2 -c
"import sys; print "2.7.18 npm ERR! gyp verb check python version
.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j npm ERR! gyp verb get
node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node
version: 16.14.0 npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '16.14.0' ] npm
ERR! gyp verb install input version string "16.14.0" npm ERR! gyp verb
install installing version: 16.14.0 npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure
was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed npm ERR! gyp verb
install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9 npm ERR! gyp verb needs
"installVersion" 9 npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good npm ERR!
gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 16.14.0 npm ERR!
gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir:
/Users/adservice.io/Documents/GitHub/kasteel-dehaar/js/node_modules/node-sass/build
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created?
/Users/adservice.io/Documents/GitHub/kasteel-dehaar/js/node_modules/node-sass/build
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file npm ERR! gyp
verb build/config.gypi writing out config file:
/Users/adservice.io/Documents/GitHub/kasteel-dehaar/js/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi
npm ERR! (node:16030) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting
process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be
read-only. npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where
the warning was created) npm ERR! gyp verb config.gypi checking for
gypi file:
/Users/adservice.io/Documents/GitHub/kasteel-dehaar/js/node_modules/node-sass/config.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file:
/Users/adservice.io/Documents/GitHub/kasteel-dehaar/js/node_modules/node-sass/common.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "make" npm
ERR! gyp info spawn
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2 npm ERR!
gyp info spawn args [ npm ERR! gyp info spawn args  
'/Users/adservice.io/Documents/GitHub/kasteel-dehaar/js/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp', npm ERR! gyp info spawn
args   '-f', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make', npm ERR! gyp info
spawn args   '-I', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args  
'/Users/adservice.io/Documents/GitHub/kasteel-dehaar/js/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args  
'/Users/adservice.io/Documents/GitHub/kasteel-dehaar/js/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args  
'/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/include/node/common.gypi', npm
ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library', npm ERR! gyp
info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args
'-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0', npm ERR! gyp
info spawn args  
'-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/adservice.io/Documents/GitHub/kasteel-dehaar/js/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args  
'-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args  
'-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/adservice.io/Documents/GitHub/kasteel-dehaar/js/node_modules/node-sass',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8', npm ERR! gyp info
spawn args   '--depth=.', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args  
'--no-parallel', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args  
'-Goutput_dir=.' npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ] npm ERR! gyp verb
command build [] npm ERR! gyp verb build type Release npm ERR! gyp
verb architecture x64 npm ERR! gyp verb node dev dir
/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0 npm ERR! gyp verb `which`
succeeded for `make` /usr/bin/make npm ERR! gyp info spawn make npm
ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'V=1', 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/libsass/src/ast.cpp:2: npm ERR!
../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1614:25: warning: loop variable 'numerator'
creates a copy from type 'const std::string' [-Wrange-loop-construct]
npm ERR!         for (const auto numerator : numerators) npm ERR!     
^ npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1614:14: note: use reference
type 'const std::string &' to prevent copying npm ERR!         for
(const auto numerator : numerators) npm ERR!             
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ npm ERR!                         & npm ERR!
../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1616:25: warning: loop variable
'denominator' creates a copy from type 'const std::string'
[-Wrange-loop-construct] npm ERR!         for (const auto denominator
: denominators) npm ERR!                         ^ npm ERR!
../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1616:14: note: use reference type 'const
std::string &' to prevent copying npm ERR!         for (const auto
denominator : denominators) npm ERR!             
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ npm ERR!                         & npm ERR! 2
warnings generated. npm ERR! In file included from
../src/libsass/src/ast_fwd_decl.cpp:1: npm ERR!
../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1614:25: warning: loop variable 'numerator'
creates a copy from type 'const std::string' [-Wrange-loop-construct]
npm ERR!         for (const auto numerator : numerators) npm ERR!     
^ npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1614:14: note: use reference
type 'const std::string &' to prevent copying npm ERR!         for
(const auto numerator : numerators) npm ERR!             
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ npm ERR!                         & npm ERR!
../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1616:25: warning: loop variable
'denominator' creates a copy from type 'const std::string'
[-Wrange-loop-construct] npm ERR!         for (const auto denominator
: denominators) npm ERR!                         ^ npm ERR!
../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1616:14: note: use reference type 'const
std::string &' to prevent copying npm ERR!         for (const auto
denominator : denominators) npm ERR!             
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ npm ERR!                         & npm ERR! 2
warnings generated. npm ERR! In file included from
../src/libsass/src/bind.cpp:3: npm ERR!
../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1614:25: warning: loop variable 'numerator'
creates a copy from type 'const std::string' [-Wrange-loop-construct]
npm ERR!         for (const auto numerator : numerators) npm ERR!     
^ npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1614:14: note: use reference
type 'const std::string &' to prevent copying npm ERR!         for
(const auto numerator : numerators) npm ERR!             
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ npm ERR!                         & npm ERR!
../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1616:25: warning: loop variable
'denominator' creates a copy from type 'const std::string'
[-Wrange-loop-construct] npm ERR!         for (const auto denominator
: denominators) npm ERR!                         ^ npm ERR!
../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1616:14: note: use reference type 'const
std::string &' to prevent copying npm ERR!         for (const auto
denominator : denominators) npm ERR!             
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ npm ERR!                         & npm ERR! 2
warnings generated. npm ERR! In file included from
../src/libsass/src/check_nesting.cpp:4: npm ERR! In file included from
../src/libsass/src/check_nesting.hpp:4: npm ERR!
../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1614:25: warning: loop variable 'numerator'
creates a copy from type 'const std::string' [-Wrange-loop-construct]
npm ERR!         for (const auto numerator : numerators) npm ERR!     
^ npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1614:14: note: use reference
type 'const std::string &' to prevent copying npm ERR!         for
(const auto numerator : numerators) npm ERR!             
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ npm ERR!                         & npm ERR!
../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1616:25: warning: loop variable
'denominator' creates a copy from type 'const std::string'
[-Wrange-loop-construct] npm ERR!         for (const auto denominator
: denominators) npm ERR!                         ^ npm ERR!
../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1616:14: note: use reference type 'const
std::string &' to prevent copying npm ERR!         for (const auto
denominator : denominators) npm ERR!             
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ npm ERR!                         & npm ERR! 2
warnings generated. npm ERR! In file included from
../src/libsass/src/color_maps.cpp:2: npm ERR!
../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1614:25: warning: loop variable 'numerator'
creates a copy from type 'const std::string' [-Wrange-loop-construct]
npm ERR!         for (const auto numerator : numerators) npm ERR!     
^ npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1614:14: note: use reference
type 'const std::string &' to prevent copying npm ERR!         for
(const auto numerator : numerators) npm ERR!             
warnings generated. npm ERR! In file included from
../src/libsass/src/util.cpp:3: npm ERR!
../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1614:25: warning: loop variable 'numerator'
creates a copy from type 'const std::string' [-Wrange-loop-construct]
npm ERR!         for (const auto numerator : numerators) npm ERR!     
^ npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1614:14: note: use reference
type 'const std::string &' to prevent copying npm ERR!         for
(const auto numerator : numerators) npm ERR!             
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ npm ERR!                         & npm ERR!
../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1616:25: warning: loop variable
'denominator' creates a copy from type 'const std::string'
[-Wrange-loop-construct] npm ERR!         for (const auto denominator
: denominators) npm ERR!                         ^ npm ERR!
../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1616:14: note: use reference type 'const
std::string &' to prevent copying npm ERR!         for (const auto
denominator : denominators) npm ERR!             
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ npm ERR!                         & npm ERR! 2
warnings generated. npm ERR! In file included from
../src/libsass/src/values.cpp:3: npm ERR! In file included from
../src/libsass/src/values.hpp:4: npm ERR!
../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1614:25: warning: loop variable 'numerator'
creates a copy from type 'const std::string' [-Wrange-loop-construct]
npm ERR!         for (const auto numerator : numerators) npm ERR!     
^ npm ERR! ../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1614:14: note: use reference
type 'const std::string &' to prevent copying npm ERR!         for
(const auto numerator : numerators) npm ERR!             
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ npm ERR!                         & npm ERR!
../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1616:25: warning: loop variable
'denominator' creates a copy from type 'const std::string'
[-Wrange-loop-construct] npm ERR!         for (const auto denominator
: denominators) npm ERR!                         ^ npm ERR!
../src/libsass/src/ast.hpp:1616:14: note: use reference type 'const
std::string &' to prevent copying npm ERR!         for (const auto
denominator : denominators) npm ERR!             
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ npm ERR!                         & npm ERR! 2
warnings generated. npm ERR! In file included from
../src/binding.cpp:1: npm ERR! In file included from
../../nan/nan.h:60: npm ERR! In file included from
/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/include/node/node.h:63: npm ERR!
In file included from
/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/include/node/v8.h:30: npm ERR!
/Users/adservice.io/.node-gyp/16.14.0/include/node/v8-internal.h:492:38:
error: no template named 'remove_cv_t' in namespace 'std'; did you
mean 'remove_cv'? npm ERR!             !std::is_same<Data,
std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data); npm ERR!                 
~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~ npm ERR!                                     
remove_cv npm ERR!
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits:715:50:
note: 'remove_cv' declared here npm ERR! template <class _Tpstruct
_LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS remove_cv npm ERR!                                                  ^ npm ERR! 1 error generated. npm ERR! make: ***
[Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1 npm ERR! gyp ERR!
build error  npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit
code: 2 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit
(/Users/adservice.io/Documents/GitHub/kasteel-dehaar/js/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:520:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
(node:internal/child_process:291:12) npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin
21.5.0 npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/adservice.io/Documents/GitHub/kasteel-dehaar/js/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
"rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags="
"--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library=" npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd
/Users/adservice.io/Documents/GitHub/kasteel-dehaar/js/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.0 npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v
v3.8.0 npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok  npm ERR! Build failed with error
code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!    
/Users/adservice.io/.npm/_logs/2022-06-08T14_30_50_295Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: this is what I can find from entire log : `no template named 'remove_cv_t' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'remove_cv'?`

- check where you mentioned this

Comment: Because you're trying to use `node-sass`, which is deprecated.

Comment: node-sass version should be matched with node version, or switch to dart sass. Check for some explanation, https://stackoverflow.com/a/69505038/3731501

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok what was happening the node-sass versions were deprecated and outdated. so I removed my current node-sass version and downgraded them. And installed them again. This fixed it. Thank u anyways!