# Laravel with Vue getting some error after run npm install

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, npm

This is my project that uses the old package and I trying to set up for development to update some feature functions When running npm install I am getting the error message.

I use the Laravel 5.8

Node v18.10.0

npm v8.19.2

Here is the message error after running npm install.

```
npm ERR! path /Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /usr/local/bin/node /Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.15.0 | darwin | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (/Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:484:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:406:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at F (/Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/which/which.js:68:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at E (/Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/gms-admin/Desktop/Development/khm-billing/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.15.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/gms-admin/.npm/_logs/2022-09-30T03_16_27_848Z-debug-0.log
```

Please help, appreciated for helping me thanks.

Comment: Is this windows?

Comment: Mismatched Node and node-sass versions. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69505038/3731501 . Don't use the latest Node version if you want to avoid incompatibilities, stick to LTS

Comment: Please share more details. What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Which OS do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I already solve this issue by downgrade note js

```
nvm install 13.14.0

nvm use 13.14.0
```

and remove `node_module` and `package.lock.josn`

```
npm install
```

Note: I use `Laradock` with `Docker`

Answer (score -1):

first, delete node_modules folder.

then run  => npm config set python "C:\Python27\python.exe"

and the last one is running  => npm install --global windows-build-tools

Comment: "System Darwin 21.6.0" and the paths within the stacktrace look more like MacOS, don't they? How does your answer related to that?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You have two options here for solve your problem regarding python module path.

Option 1 :
You need to install windows-build-tools and then Your error will be solved. Just run this command in your terminal.

```
npm i windows-build-tools
```

Option 2 :
You just need to Install Python In Your PC ( If Not Installed ) and then add python to your PATH variable. Using environment variable.

```
npm config set python /path/to/python.exe
```

Comment: "System Darwin 21.6.0" and the paths within the stacktrace look more like MacOS, don't they? How does your answer related to that?

Comment: Keep supporting us rather than faulting each user post. Please suggest us how can we give more supportive way of answers rather than giving negative impressions.

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. Also, it would be better to post answers that **really** relate to the given questions