# ERR! build error when I tried use a template

Tags: macos, vue.js, templates

I try to use a Vue template, but when I try to run npm install, I get this errors:

gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2

npm ERR! node-sass@6.0.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@6.0.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

I tried deleting node_modules and package-lock.json and re running npm install, but this doesn’t work.

Comment: Node version mismatches one that the project was designed to run with, specifically node-sass dependency

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69504798/forked-vuejs-app-gives-error-on-npm-install/69505038#69505038